# Oracle accesses wrong table

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I'm using Oracle 11g Express edition. I created two different users (user1, user2) on two different tablespaces. Each user has the same set of tables (same table names, columns, data types). I configured my app to connect to user2 but it always accesses to the tables of user1. My expect is that it will access to the tables of user2. I doubled check about username/password used to connect to database. I don't know what's going on here!

I found the answer: The problem is not at Oracle. It's because of Hibernate, I found the answer here: http://www.schakko.de/2014/01/07/hibernate-uses-wrong-schema-during-schema-validation/

Sorry for any confusing I made ^^

Comment: Is there difference in table data too?

Comment: It looks like, the issue is with your App configuration and not oracle. Please have a look at the configuration files for your application.

Comment: I don't know where's the problem because when I deleted user1, my app then immediately connected to user2 !!

Comment: There's only one place for setting username/password used to connect to the database in my app so I'm sure that it's not because of my app configuration

Comment: yet another reason to avoid Hibernate... :/

Answer (score 1):

One solution is setting the **hibernate.default_schema** property to fit your user (in your persistence unit or as env property using 
**-Dhibernate.default_schema=YOUR_SCHEMA** jvm param).

Other solution is revoking privileges to access the other schemas for your user. This should not be allowed also beacuse of petential security issues (unless such access it's required for that particular user).

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.* 
  from user2.table1 t
```